# I installed the quick.db, but it still doesn't working

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'quick.db'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Igor\github\litchbot\index.js
```

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "json": "^9.0.6",
    "quick.db":"^7.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any problems with downloading it, or are you sure it downloaded **everything** successfully? If you're using Windows, you can open CMD as administrator (make sure it's as administrator) and type `npm -g install windows-build-tools node-gyp --save` and then download quick.db once its done.

Comment: Yes! I'm sure!
I used this commands:
``npm install --global --production --vs2015 --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools``
``npm install --global --production --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools node-gyp``

Comment: It is returning this error codes:
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\Igor\\github\\litchbot\\index.js' ]

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird.. Do you mind trying to install quick.db again and perhaps take a screenshot if you see errors during the download?

Comment: Ok! I'll try it

Comment: I don't know why, but always when I try to install a file with npm, a new terminal open and install the code...And when it's done, I can't see the logs, because the new terminal automatically close.

Comment: Weird... Are you sure you did `npm -g install windows-build-tools node-gyp --save` in cmd as administrator? Like exactly `npm -g install windows-build-tools node-gyp --save`?

Comment: Now, in the installation, I received this inssue:
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Comment: Well seeing a WARN is usually normal I believe

Comment: I had these errors:
https://i.imgur.com/KmMXCqg.jpg

Comment: I see... You opened cmd.exe as administrator right?

Comment: Yes, I open the PowerShell in administrator

Comment: That is very weird... and just double checking, you ran `npm -g install windows-build-tools node-gyp --save` right?

Comment: In the installation a error ocurrs and show a message like "Node is not an internal program", but the terminal close so fast and I can't read it all, "node is not an internal module" something like this...

Comment: How about you add me on Discord, I can try to help you out :)

Comment: Yes, my discord id is: ~Igor~#3404

Comment: I found the error:
'prebuild-install' is not known as an internal or external command, an operable program or a batch file
'npm' is not recognized as an internal command